# Auto backup when USB Drive inserted

Tags: bash, usb-drive, udev

If this is not the best place to post this question, can you please direct me to a more appropriate place to post this.

**What I am trying to do:**

I have a USB drive, it is `fat32` and its name is `JavaClasses`. Whenever I plug it in it is mounted and its accessible path is `/media/bill/JavaClasses`. I have a script that when I run it, it checks to see if the `JavaClasses` directory exists, if it does, it will make a directory with this format, `yyyymmddhhmm`.  Then the script will copy (backup) my eclipse directory to this new directory.

I have created a new rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-javaclasses.rules`.  This will launch the above script.  The script has a 2 second delay to allow the mounting.

**Current situation:**

The script runs fine if I run in manually. It does not run automatically when the drive is plugged in.

**The command line and info:**

This is the command in the `85-javaclasses.rules`.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6545", RUN+="/home/bill/bin/javaclasses.sh"
```

This is what I get when I run

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/sdb1


looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/usb10/10-1/10-1.4':
    KERNELS=="10-1.4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="10"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="200mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="001A4D5E4020ED5199130595"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="2197"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Kingston"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6545"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="DataTraveler 2.0"
```

Can anyone point me in a direction to have this resolved? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Just try a simple command loop, very low processing power, but useful.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0
while [ true ]
    do if [ $x = 0 ]
        then if [ -s /media/myflashdrive/* ]
            then bash /home/user/myscript.sh
            x=1
        fi
        else if [ -s /media/myflashdrive/* ]
            then true
            else x=0
        fi
     fi
sleep 10
done
```

Save this in /etc/ and add this line to /etc/rc.local :

```
bash /etc/this_script.sh &
```

Make sure you add that before the exit 0.
Done! Whenever your flashdrive mounts myscript.sh will run, then when its unmounted, x will equal 0 again and the script will start looking for it again for you to plug it in!

Comment: This will run a non stop loop looking for the media every 10 seconds.  Once it backs up the program stops.  The problem here is if I want to back up 2-3 times a day with out restarting.  I am looking for a soution that could use udev.